# Objects Accessing in JS vs TS

Tags: typescript, sorting, object

I am working on a migration project from JS to TS.
I have this Object.keys function in Javascript

```
computed: {
    sortedTasks() {
      let tasks = this.tasks;

      // sort tasks by level
      let sortedTasks = Object.keys(tasks)
        .sort((a, b) =>
          tasks[a].level > tasks[b].level
            ? 1
            : tasks[b].level > tasks[a].level
            ? -1
            : 0
        )
        .map(k => tasks[k]);

      for (let task of sortedTasks) {
        task.duration = this.duration(task);
      }

      return sortedTasks;
    }
  },
```

I am trying to do the same here in Typescript but it's giving me an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'level')

```
const sortedTasks = computed(() => {
      let tasksPreview = ref<any>(props.tasks)

      let result = Object.keys(tasksPreview)
        .sort((a, b) =>
          tasksPreview[a].level > tasksPreview[b].level
            ? 1
            : tasksPreview[b].level > tasksPreview[a].level
            ? -1
            : 0
        )
        .map(k => tasksPreview[k]);

      for (let task of result) {
        task.duration = duration(task);
      }

      return result
    
      })
```

Comment: You've told typescript to assume that the type of `tasksPreview` should be `any`. This basically means, "disable type safety for this variable". Either remove `<any>` or change it to be the correct type.

Comment: tasksPreview is = to an object btw. If I removed it I get another error : 
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Ref<{ [x: string]: any; } | undefined>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Ref<{ [x: string]: any; } | undefined>'.

Comment: can you provide some `input data` and expected `output data`, so that we can help?

Comment: can it be possible that some tasks in `tasksPreview` have keys but value is `undefined`?

Comment: @MEAG that means that that you have to check if `tasksPreview` is `undefined` before you use it.

Comment: Try this... `Object.keys(tasksPreview).filter(key => tasksPreview[key]).sort(.....)`... But then it only sorts those tasks whose value is not `undefined`.

Comment: Like for example, If I try your logic with `const tasksPreview: any = {
    "t1": {
        level: 2
    },
    "t2": {
        level: 1
    },
    "t3": {
        level: 3
    },
    "t4": undefined
}` it fails with the same error.

Comment: That means you will have to take care of the scenariio where a task can be undefined. Either use a filter(as I have given in the previous comment) or do something..

Comment: I believe it's working, but give me some time to confirm. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I tried the .filer solution, but I think It changed the data format to an array, instead of an object. This caused errors in the for loop below it, and broke the v-for in the HTML part. As I'm using Vue3.  Any advice?